# Telnet over half-duplex comms link - negotiation parameters

Tags: c, embedded, telnet, legacy, obsolete

Our embedded system needs a Telnet (over serial) interface, due to hardware / legacy system it's working over a half-duplex link (RS485). Yes, I know - no, we can't change it, the industry likes it that way.

The problem with this is that while we're sending a screenfull of text to the terminal, the user can be pushing buttons and sending data back up the wire.

Telnet supports the IAC->GA (Go Ahead) command to signal to the user terminal it **can begin** sending data, but there is no info in any of the RFC's I've read about what tells the user terminal to **stop** sending data so we can refresh the screen.

Unfortunately all of the RFC's beyond about 1973 assume that the SGA ([Suppress Go Ahead](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc858)) mode will be used so it gets very little mention. Unfortunately there seems to be no single RFC or other document that actually covers the entirety of the protocol.

Does anyone have any info / links that document the telnet protocol (or just the Go Ahead behaviour) more fully? I realise some of it is probably written on parchment with green stripes ;)

**RE-Edit:** Why the "off-topic" closure of this *programming* question? Telnet is layer 7 of the OSI model y'know...

Comment: I also wonder why this was closed.  Just because telnet and RS485 aren't widespread hot topics doesn't mean the question isn't valid or useful.

Comment: I suspect people saw "RS485" and assumed it was hardware or something like that. Damn kids, get off my lawn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahhh... RS-485...  I remember it well!  :-)

The GA definition is broken (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc596) but should be okay for a serial-line implementation because there is no break-up of packets.

What you're asking for is a "reverse break":

> "Reverse break" is a means by which a computer connected to a
> terminal by a half-duplex path may regain control of the path for
> further typeout after previously having relinquished it.

By it's very nature, a "break" (reverse or otherwise) must be out-of-band on a half-duplex connection since it needs to be able to be sent at any time.

*EDIT: New info as a result of a chat:*  However, if you don't expect to be interrupting an actual transmission ([RFC393](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0393), reverse-break case "b") *and* the side with the go-ahead token does not switch the hardware to "transmit" mode except when actually transmitting (RS-485 cannot receive when in this mode even if no data is being sent) *and* an occasional corrupted/truncated transmission is tolerable *and* the telnet program correctly implements this rather unusual corner-case, *then* sending this code in-band may be acceptable.

Another way I can think to deal with this would be to hack the client side Telnet program to periodically send a "go-ahead" packet to the server even when it has nothing else to send.  This would allow the server to do an update and do "go-ahead" in return; it's somewhat like "token ring".  You wouldn't even have to delay -- when receiving "go-ahead", send all pending data (might be none) and then return the "go-ahead".

**Possible Alternative Solution:**

Since you control the ser->ip device as well, why not simply have a specialized protocol between the server and device?

- server sends `STX data stream ETX`
- client send `STX data stream ETX`
- repeat with no delay

If either side has no data in its data buffer, then it's just an `STX ETX` pair effectively telling the other side to "go ahead".  If nothing comes from the other side within 250ms, resend `ETX`

You could even extend this to have error detection by going `STX data stream ETX CRC1 CRC2` with a `NAK` (instead of `STX ...`) reply in the case of a detected error, and causing a re-transmit of the entire last packet.

Comment: Interesting - but we don't have control of the client; we are the server, talking over a 485-link which is passing through an IP encoder and then being accessed by the user using something like PuTTY.

What sounds like it might work is that when we want to start talking we send a "reverse break", followed by a screenfull of data, followed by a "Go Ahead" - does that sound sensible?

Comment: This is getting more complicated as you're limited to what the terminal can support and converter can support.  What make of 485<=>TCP device are you using?  What echo and line-mode options are you negotiating?

Comment: We're using a home-spun homage to remserial. We haven't got as far as negotiating echo/line-mode. Another wrinkle worth mentioning is that some of the screens are displaying live data from our system, so the screen updates at ~1Hz in some cases. Navigation is using arrow keys, logging in etc. is done as usual command-line style. Legacy systems are fun eh? :D

Comment: Well, that is a bit of a problem.  I can't fit my idea in a comment so I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @JohnU, When you get something working, I'd like to hear what solution you settled upon.

Comment: So far all I've worked out is that sending a break, then sending the data, then sending a go-ahead is possibly the answer. I did mislead slightly in in the above comment - one of our applications uses an IP converter but the other one is straight RS485 and we would like to use a terminal interface over that too - so the problem is really just "HTF to do half-duplex Telnet properly"? The ancients seemed to manage it, but they got killed off about RFC400 and never referred to again.

Comment: There is no fully functional half-duplex telnet where either side can send at any time.  If you can enable 485 receive and transmit _separately_ then you can implement a line-break by just writing the break over incoming data and have the other side detect it by reading as it transmits and noticing that there is corruption on the line.  Ethernet works somewhat this way as it is originally half-duplex.

Comment: True there is no standard where both sides can send at *any* time, but surely by forcing the use of GO_AHEAD and BREAK (or something) to signal the other end may / may not Tx it should work with only the occasional BREAK going missing. Failing that, a round-robin / token-ring style behaviour would be acceptable with each side taking turns.

The protocol appears to support this, as RFC596 is a discussion of *deprecating* this behaviour.

Comment: It's the BREAK that is the problem.  How do you communicate it?  If it's a character code and transmitted without heed it may collide with a transmission the other direction.  Both the incoming data _and the break_ will be corrupted.  Not to mention that 485 is typically not listening while transmitting (or it would see its own outgoing characters).

Comment: Exactly, but I think we can tolerate the occasional collision of a BREAK character. What I'm digging for is a description of the expected behaviour - is a BREAK the right thing to send to shut the other end up or is it one of those de-facto things that might/probably works etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18181/discussion-between-brian-white-and-john-u)